# Trouble with ember select

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to get a simple belongsTo relationship working with an HTML select element.

My app records students. Each student is assigned to a category.

I have a category model:

```
import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.Model.extend({
  code: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string')
});
```

And a student model which - amongst many other things - belongs to a category.

```
import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.Model.extend({
  //...
  category: DS.belongsTo('category', {async: true}),
  //...
});
```

I want to allow the user to select the students category in a template so my route loads in a list of category objects:

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('student', params.student_id);
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    //...
    controller.set('categories', this.store.find('category'));
    //...
  }
});
```

My template includes this (edit: I use `"content.id"` for the value path not `"content"` as originally stated but it seems to have no impact on the problem):

```
<label>Category:&nbsp;</label>
{{view "select" 
   content=categories 
   optionValuePath="content.id" 
   optionLabelPath="content.description" 
   selection=category}}
```

**My expectation** is that this will allow me to choose an item from the list and it will update my models category accordingly.

**What actually happens** is that the list works but if I change the selection the select element goes blank.

The resulting HTML is like this:

```
<select id="ember955" class="ember-view ember-select">
  <option id="ember1199" class="ember-view" value="16">Category A</option>
  <option id="ember1202" class="ember-view" value="17">Category B</option>
  <option id="ember1205" class="ember-view" value="18">Category C</option>
  <option id="ember1208" class="ember-view" value="19">Category D</option>
  <option id="ember1211" class="ember-view" value="20">Category E</option>
  <option id="ember1214" class="ember-view" value="21">Category F</option>
  <option id="ember1217" class="ember-view" value="22">Category G</option>
</select>
```

Have I done this correctly? Is there a pattern I am missing?

EDIT:

I have replicated this as best as I can in a [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/forixeyuku/3/edit?html,js,output) but the problem I have is not happening. Its very odd, the select element is populated correctly and it even seems to update the category correctly. The only problem is that if I change the original selection the select box goes blank.

Comment: so, are you expecting that by selecting the category it will be assigned to the user ?. would you mind creating a JS Fiddle ?

Answer (score 1):

I would expect to see a unique property, such as `id`, referenced for `optionValuePath` instead of the entire object.

So instead of `optionValuePath="content"`, it would be `optionValuePath="content.id"`:

```
<label>Category:&nbsp;</label>
{{view "select" 
   content=categories 
   optionValuePath="content.id" 
   optionLabelPath="content.description" 
   selection=category}}
```

Comment: That shouldn't cause an issue... putting `content` is perfectly valid as it would set the selected object instead of only its id

Comment: ^ Is that right? `optionValuePath` is used to set the `value` attribute of the corresponding `option` tag. Setting that to an `object` doesn't make sense.

Comment: when I set it to the object it simply puts the string representation of the object in the HTML like `value="<app-name@model:category::ember761:23>"`. This seems to be the default behaviour and works fine. Using object.id leads to cleaner HTML. I had been playing with this and so my original example code doesn't match the example output. This is now fixed.